# Почему некорректно останавливается BackgroundWorker?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, backgroundworker

Есть BackgroundWorker, в DoWork создаю коллецию и в ParallelForeach обрабатываю.

```
private void backgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    int cnt = (int) e.Argument;

    List<int[]> ListArrays = new List<int[]>();
    for (int i=0; i<cnt ; i++)
    {
        Random rnd = new Random((int)DateTime.Now.Ticks);
        int length = rnd.Next(5000, 100000);

        ListArrays.Add(new int[length]);

        for (int j = 0; j < ListArrays[i].Length; j++)
        {
            ListArrays[i][j] = rnd.Next(0, 1000000);
        }
    }

    int progress=0;

    Parallel.ForEach(ListArrays, item =>
        {
            if (_backgroundWorker != null)
            {
                if (_backgroundWorker.WorkerReportsProgress)
                {
                    _backgroundWorker.ReportProgress((int)(progress / (cnt / 100M)));
                }
                if (_stopThread)
                {
                    _busy.WaitOne();
                }
                if (_backgroundWorker.CancellationPending)
                {
                    e.Cancel = true;
                    return;
                }

                Worker worker = new Worker();
                worker.FindPrimes(item);
                CounterPrimes += worker.CounterPrimes;
                progress++;
            }
        });
 }
```

Есть кнопки Стоп, Пауза, Продолжить.
Просто после старта стоп работает правильно.
Но если сделать паузу, то после продолжения стоп уже не работает, почему так?

```
AutoResetEvent _busy = new AutoResetEvent(false);
bool _stopThread; 
private void StopBtn_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // _stopThread = false;
    //_busy.Set();
    _backgroundWorker.CancelAsync();
}

private void PauseBtn_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    PauseBtn.IsEnabled = false;
    _stopThread = true;
    ResumeBtn.IsEnabled = true;
}

private void ResumeBtn_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ResumeBtn.IsEnabled = false;
    PauseBtn.IsEnabled = true;
    _stopThread = false;
    _busy.Set();
}
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36153029/why-incorrectly-stops-backgroundworker

Comment: `AutoResetEvent _busy` => `_busy.Set()` разбудит только один поток.

Comment: @PetSerAl так он же отрабатывает нормально, пауза/продолжить работают. Стоп только после них не работает.

Comment: Во первых, один поток всё-таки просыпается. Во вторых, `Parallel.ForEach` вправе добавить новых потоков, если видит, что процессор простаивает. Поэтому при нажатии "продолжить", обработка вроде как возобновляется, вот только часть потоков так и продолжают спать.

Comment: @PetSerAl Если так то плохо, но суть то в том что продолжить работает, а вот стоп после него нет. Посоветуете как лучше сделать?

Comment: Сразу же проблема — вы создаёте каждый раз новый `Random` с одним и тем же seed'ом. Неудивительно, что у вас случайные значения получаются по факту одинаковыми.

Comment: Во-вторых, вы пользуетесь низкоуровневыми примитивами вместо современной TPL. Если бы вы пользовались ими _правильно_, проблем бы тоже не было. Но вы пользуетесь ими неправильно. Например, вы не защищаете доступ к разделяемой переменной `_stopThread`.

Comment: @PetSerAl (int)DateTime.Now.Ticks дает как раз разные числа.

Comment: @AlexeyKleandrov уверены, что разные? все таки там перевод int и потеря точности. А вообще лучше один раз инициировать рэндом перед циклом.А вообще лучше забыть backgroundWorker как страшный сон.и брать TPL

Comment: @vitidev Уверен и это не так критично. TPL взял, пока не помогло